# Git pull doesn't show all message

Tags: git, gitlab, git-pull

I got a problem when writing an automatic tool with git. When I added one more row I got the full message like this:

```
$ git pull
remote: Enumerating objects: 1, done.
remote: Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (1/1), done.
From gitlab.com:phamthanhlong/deploy
   5f29c00..50bc6a8  master     -> origin/master
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 branch 1/branch 1.1/Ops_Pickup_Ontime1stPerformance.py | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

But when I added more rows, I didn't get the full message

```
$ git pull
remote: Enumerating objects: 5, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
remote: Total 5 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (5/5), done.
From gitlab.com:phamthanhlong/deploy
   50bc6a8..0d40519  master     -> origin/master
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 .../Ops_Pickup_Ontime1stPerformance.py      | 94 ++++++++++++++++++++++
 1 file changed, 94 insertions(+)
```

I want to get the full name and path of the file that's been push to gitlab like this: `branch 1/branch 1.1/Ops_Pickup_Ontime1stPerformance.py`, not this: `.../Ops_Pickup_Ontime1stPerformance.py`

Comment: What do you mean by "added more rows"?

Comment: It means: I modify the file that's been uploaded like adding 1 comment, ...

Comment: I don't think you can prevent the logs from `git pull` from abbreviating the file names when the line is too long, but maybe in your script you could add `git show --stat` or `git diff --stat HEAD^ HEAD` right after the `git pull`, and extract the full path of changes files from there.

Comment: @joanis: `git merge` *is* running `git diff --stat` here (or more precisely, they share the underlying text-generating code). The abbreviated output will always be abbreviated. It's not wise to use `git diff --stat` output as computer input—use instead plumbing-command output, such as `git diff-tree`'s `:`-formatted text.

Comment: There's a fundamental flaw in your question, *I want to get the full name and path of the file that's been push[ed] to gitlab*, because *files* haven't been pushed. *Commits* have been pushed, or in your case fetched. Every commit has *every* file in it. What Git is showing you here is an abbreviation of the result of `git diff` of *two particular commits*, namely `HEAD@{1}` vs `HEAD`.

Comment: @torek thanks for the pointer to git diff-tree. It's good to know about it. So would you expect `git diff-tree HEAD@{1} HEAD` or `git diff-tree HEAD^ HEAD` will answer the OP's question?

Comment: @joanis: Well, OP probably wants `-r --name-only`, or maybe `-r --name-status`, here.  It's not all that clear. `-r` is definitely important here though.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for your support guys. After researching for a while, I finally find an answer.

After using: `git pull`, I use this command: `git diff --name-status ORIG_HEAD..`

Comment: Oh I get it now, you meant "command" everywhere you mentionned "comment". Just be aware that you're (unwittingly I'm pretty sure) confusing people in these contexts.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry for my bad english.